# calling c# method at ajax success

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

MessageBox is another ascx, I am trying to trigger Message method after ajax success but It triggers at page load.

MessageBox.ascx's page load is blank. and It has some reusable javascript/c# messagebox stuff.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/_Handler/DBFileUpload.ashx?ItemId=<%=ItemId%>",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            <% MessageBox.Message(MessageBox.MessageType.Success, "Congratz!", "File uploaded.")%>
        },
        error: function (errorData) {

        }
    });
```

**SOLUTION**

as Igor pointed out, I return the javascript function so I can call directly at ajax success.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/_Handler/DBFileUpload.ashx?ItemId=<%=ItemId%>",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        window[<%= MessageBox.MessageJS(MessageBox.MessageType.Success, "Congratz!", "File uploaded.")%>](arguments);
    },
    error: function (errorData) {

    }
   });
```

Comment: code `MessageBox.Message(...` is executed server-side during `Page.Render`, not when `ajax.success` fires.

Comment: yeah, how can I make it work at only ajax success

Comment: you can output (when rendering the page) javascript/html required to show a message box on the client, and trigger that javascript inside `ajax.success`

Comment: Igor, I made it like that and worked. Do you want to create an answer so I can accept or should I do myself?

Comment: ok I also added the solution code to question. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output (when rendering the page server-side) javascript/html required to show a message box on the client, and trigger that javascript inside `ajax.success`.

Answer (score 3):

I would first recommend you taking some online courses on client side development, because what you are trying would never work.
Secondly what you are trying to do is very easy using javascript alert;

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/_Handler/DBFileUpload.ashx?ItemId=<%=ItemId%>",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
           alert("File uploaded.")
        },
        error: function (errorData) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can't. Javascript runs client side, C# runs server side.

In fact, your server will run all the C# code, generating Javascript. The Javascript then, is run in the browser. As said in the comments, the compiler doesn't know Javascript.

To call the functionality on your server, you'll have to use techniques such as AJAX..

```
 $.ajax({
       url: "/_Handler/DBFileUpload.ashx?ItemId=<%=ItemId%>",
      data: formData,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
              //if you have any data return from ajax call it's in data object

                 $("div").html("success");
        },
        error: function (errorData) {

      }
  });
```